# EditText always have 2 numbers and limit values

Tags: java, android

I want to achieve an EditText for a timer, like the native timer in the alarm app of the Galaxy S5. Here is a screenshot:

[image: native alarm]

Basically the EditText is limited to 2 values, but it always have 2 numbers, and it limits the minutes and seconds to a value between 0 and 59. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the EditText watcher, i.e. something that monitors the field and corrects values.

Android provides [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

So, implement the function..

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

     //Convert this to a number i.e. 
     int myNum = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

     //Examine the value and replace..
     if (myNum > 60)
     {
       s.replace(0, s.length(), "60", 0, 2);
     }
}
```

Note though, Android does also provide `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` callbacks so, perhaps these would be better for you. Principle however is the same as above.

I hope this resolves your issue. :)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i wanted, do you know how i can remove the first number of the two, when the user type another number and place the typed number behind the number that was last before?

Comment: Do you mean this:

Display shows:

00:00:33

User attempts to enter 90...

You then want to display 33 instead?

If you mean that then:

I would recommend that you store the hours, minutes and seconds. Then in 'afterTextChanged' if (myNum > 60), do s.replace(0, s.length(), numVal, 0, 2);

where numVal is the string that you stored after the user previously entered it. You should store it in afterTextChanged, in an 'else' statement paired with the above 'if' statement, i.e. in the case where myNum is NOT greater than 60.